# Symfony - Autoloader can't find class / composer error

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

When I tried adding a new dependency to my project with `composer require xyz` I got the following error:

> The autoloader expected class "PackageVersions\Versions" to be defined in file ".../vendor/ocramius/package-versions/src/PackageVersions/Versions.php".
>
> The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

I dug into that file, to see that the `Versions`class is there, in the right file, but with a the following name:

`Versions_composer_tmp0`

The namespace declarations seem to be good in the entire project, as well as php opening tags (I read that might cause such problems).

Additionally, I remarked that all the `use` statements in the `Installer` class file, which is the one that creates the `Versions` class are marked by phpstorm as `Undefined Classes`. They all should be found in the namespace `Composer\xyz`.

I tried the following without succes:

- clearing the symfony cache
- clearing composer cache
- `composer self-update`
- deleting the `ocramius` vendor folder so that composer would download it again
- renaming the class, which is pointless since the entire purpose of this `Versions` class is to be rewritten with each `composer install` or `composer update`

**edit:**

I'm trying to install `1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle`, the `Ocramius/PackageVersions`is already there as a dependency probably (I did not require it manually)

**edit 2:**

I just saw that `server:run` won't work either. So the problem is definitely not related to the bundle I'm trying to install. I managed to make the server run by renaming the class from `Versions_composer_tmp0` to `Versions`.

Comment: Try install another package in another directory (as `var/www/temp`), like `$ sudo composer require symfony/symfony` and see if it's working or not.

Comment: Yes, using composer. If you have composer installed globally, you can proceed with the command I wrote above, or if not ( you can install composer globally as stated here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-14-04) , install composer just for this 'project' (`test`), and then run the command.

Comment: thx for helping @DanCostinel I had composer installed globally and it worked without any problem

Comment: What package from ocramius are you trying to install?

Comment: I'm not trying to install any ocramius package, they already are there as (I guess) dependencies of other projects. `ocramius/package-versions` and `ocramius/proxy-manager`. I'll note that in an edit.

Comment: 1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle with symfony 2.8

Comment: For me it worked. I used symfony 2.8.3 and I'm following this for installing the package: https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110014/discussion-between-barthy-b-and-dan-costinel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is a composer issue:

[composer/composer#5237](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5237)

Ocramius released a fix/workaround for this:

[Ocramius/PackageVersions - Release 1.0.4](https://github.com/Ocramius/PackageVersions/releases/tag/1.0.4)